# Percona 5.7.24 : How to fix disk slave storage full

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, percona, master-slave-replication, percona-server

I find that my slave disk is full, but I don't understand what makes it full.
Can anyone help me explain what this file is?
And how it is formed, so that it makes lots of files that make storage full.
Check in mysql error log I did not find anything

Some file types that make my disk full like this:
[image: screenshoot file in disk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#sql` files are temp tables generated by `ALTER` and other maintenance commands.  You will need to find what that command is.  At that point, you will probably find that it is in a tight loop, either spawning off process after process, or crashing and restarting.

Other clues:  The table name (for many of them) includes "ib916".  The table is about 7GB in size (disk footprint).

Comment: I see, then how to solve `alter` tables with large data so that `#sql` temp table files don't stack up a lot?

I just realized, this happens when there are `alter` migrations on my mySQL. thx

Comment: "How to solve"?  Don't let them stack up.  What is causing them to be issued in parallel?  `ALTER` is likely to be I/O-bound, thereby making parallelism futile.

Comment: Thank a lot for your advice @RickJames . They are issued in parallel because the `ALTER` table is large so it need a long process, maybe. I just found a case like this.

Comment: @fajarhide - Well that explains running out of disk space.